# What is the proper way to take a directory input with spaces from a user? (Python3)

Tags: python, input, python-3.4, os.walk

I am trying to take a directory path via a user input then walk through the directories using os.walk().  My program breaks if I try to enter a path with spaces (i.e. "Users/User/Folder with space/Folder/").

**What is the proper way to take a directory input with spaces from a user? (Python3)**

My code looks something like:

```
fileDirectory = input("Enter in a path to import")

try:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(shlex.quote(fileDirectory)):
            for f in files:
                print(f)
                fileLocation = os.path.join(root, f) #Saves the path of the file
                print(fileLocation)
                size = os.path.getsize(fileLocation) #Gets the file size
                print(size)
                filePath, fileExt = os.path.splitext(fileLocation) #splits path and     extension, defines two variables
                print(fileExt)
                print(filePath)
except Exception as msg:
print(msg)
```

Comment: How and where exactly does it break? I just ran a test where I printed out `root` `dirs` and `files` and did not find any error on Python 3.4.

Comment: The program runs when there are no spaces, but where there are spaces in the directory, it just ends.  I tried to handle the error with a "try/except" clause, but nothing is printed for the 'exception.'  Sorry I don't have more information.

Comment: Can you describe what your `some code` is intended to do?

Comment: One part of the code is meant to print attributes of each file. here is one example:          'for f in files:
             print(f)
             fileLocation = os.path.join(root, f) #Saves the path of the file
             print(fileLocation)
             size = os.path.getsize(fileLocation) #Gets the file size
             print(size)
             filePath, fileExt = os.path.splitext(fileLocation) #splits path and extension, defines two variables
             print(fileExt)
             print(filePath)'

Comment: Please update your question. SO comments do not support newlines!

Comment: @user3650905: you can [edit] your question to provide a new information such as add the code with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [shlex.quote](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote).

In this case you would want:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(shlex.quote(fileDirectory)):
    #some code...
```

Comment: You should not use `shlex.quote()`. Just pass the directory path directly: `os.walk(fileDirectory)`. It doesn't matter whether it has spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate function that returns you a valid directory:

```
import os

def get_directory_from_user(prompt='Input a directory path'):
    while True:
        path = input(prompt)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            return path
        print('%r is not a directory. Try again.' % path)
```

It doesn't matter whether `path` has spaces or not. Just pass it to `os.walk()` as is:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(get_directory_from_user()):
    ...
```